# Update the content of one file to another in shell with pattern

Tags: shell

I have a whose contents should be updated on another file. How do I do this using sed command?

### A.txt

```
{
username:someuser,
password:somepass
}
```

### B.txt

```
{
username:tempuser,
password:temppass
}
```

So I want values of A.txt should be updated in B.txt. These files have other distinct data so I need to use pattern matching.

I tried following commands

```
old=`sed -n "/{/{n;p;n;p}" B.txt` 
new=`sed -n "/{/{n;p;n;p}" A.txt` 
sed -i -e "s/$old/$new/g" B.txt
```

However the newline between username & password is getting removed and hence not able to replace.

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Comment: I tried following commands       
`old=\`sed -n "/{/{n;p;n;p}" B.txt\``
`new=\`sed -n "/{/{n;p;n;p}" A.txt\``
`sed -i -e "s/$old/$new/g" B.txt`
However the newline between username & password is getting removed and hence not able to replace.

Comment: Please don't post code, log entries, or configuration as a comment. Instead, us the "edit" link below your question to edit it into the question.

Comment: Updated the question